# How to determine the projection (2D or 3D) of a matplotlib axes object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, 2d, projection

In Python's matplotlib library it is easy to specify the projection of an axes object on creation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
```

But how do I determine the projection of an existing axes object? There's no `ax.get_projection`, `ax.properties` contains no "projection" key, and a quick google search hasn't turned up anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an automated way, but there are obviously some properties that only the 3D projection has (e.g. `zlim`).

So you could write a little helper function to test if its 3D or not:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def axesDimensions(ax):
    if hasattr(ax, 'get_zlim'): 
        return 3
    else:
        return 2


fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')

print "ax1: ", axesDimensions(ax1)
print "ax2: ", axesDimensions(ax2)
```

Which prints:

```
ax1:  2
ax2:  3
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept this answer because it does the trick, but I'm going to keep a lookout for a built-in way of doing this. Will update my question if I find anything.

Answer (score 5):

*It turns out that the answer given here is actually a better answer to this question: [python check if figure is 2d or 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563244/python-check-if-figure-is-2d-or-3d)
And the answer i provided at that duplicate is a better answer to this question.*

In any case, you can use the `name` of the axes. This is the string that determines the projection.

```
plt.gca().name   or   ax.name
```

if `ax` is the axes.

A 3D axes' name will be `"3d"`. A 2D axes' name will be `"rectilinear"`, `"polar"` or some other name depending on the type of plot. Custom projections will have their custom names.

So instead of `ax.get_projection()` just use `ax.name`.

Comment: That might be the default name, but it can be changed at any time by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the projection, `ax` will be a different class.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')

print(type(ax1))  # <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
print(type(ax2))  # <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot'>

isinstance(ax1, plt.Axes)  # True
isinstance(ax1, Axes3D)    # False
isinstance(ax2, plt.Axes)  # True - Axes3D is also a plt.Axes
isinstance(ax2, Axes3D)    # True
```

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward and solid approach. In my case, I wanted to check whether an Axes used a polar projection, which can be similarly done as `isinstance(ax, plt.PolarAxes)`.