# python check if figure is 2d or 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, axes

In matlab with a figure, to check if it is 3D figure or 2D figure I use:

```
V=axis;
```

and check the number of components of V (4 for 2d figure, 6 for 3d figure).
How can i implement this with python and matplotlib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the projection (2D or 3D) of a matplotlib axes object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333446/how-to-determine-the-projection-2d-or-3d-of-a-matplotlib-axes-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name` of the axes.

```
plt.gca().name   or   ax.name
```

if `ax` is the axes.

A 3D axes' name will be `"3d"`. A 2D axes' name will be `"rectilinear"`, `"polar"` or some other name depending on the type of plot.

You can therefore check

```
if  ax.name == "3d":
    # axes is 3D, do something
else:
    # axes is not 3D, do something else
```

---

You can also check for the limits, as proposed in an answer to [the question this is a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333446/how-to-determine-the-projection-2d-or-3d-of-a-matplotlib-axes-object?noredirect=1&lq=1). In this way you would get the limits

```
def get_limits(ax):
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    if hasattr(ax, 'get_zlim'): 
        zlim = ax.get_zlim()
        return xlim, ylim, zlim
    else:
        return xlim, ylim
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I get the axis value for a 3d figure? thanks for support

Comment: In Matlab : V=axis ,  # I get 6 values two for each (x,y,z) how can implements it in python if i have a 3d figure?

Comment: x_min, x_max for x axis, y_min y_max for y axis, z_min , z_max for z axis.  The problem is the  that in input  have a Figure object and a I have to determine if is 3d or 2d after that i have to set axis values (min and max) for each of them (x,y,z)

Comment: Ok, so the duplicate answer is actually telling you how to do that. But I updated the answer anyways.

Comment: Thanks but i prefer your answer

Comment: when I use: `plt.gca()` it returns an Axis object, but if my figure is a 3d figure what it returns? I need to use `get_zscale()` method of the class mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.

Comment: In both cases an axes object is returned. In the 2D case it's `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` and in the 3D case a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot`, which has the same properties as the `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D`.

Comment: I will explain better my problem , I need to translate in python a matlab function that take as input the figure number , so this function first check if a figure is 2d or 3d after that resize the axis . If I use plt.axis()  on 2d axis I get a vector of four component, and if i use it ona 3d axes? Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Using `plt.axis()` on a 3D plot also returns a four-element tuple. Those are the limits of `x` and `y` of the 3D plot.